# AWS Lambda CloudWatch Failed to deserialize log message

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

we ran into an issue with AWS Lambda and CloudWatch:
it fails when it tries to log billing details into the console:

```
REPORT RequestId: ae61585c-9bda-480f-94e6-5b72f4ed7b17  Duration: 319.40 ms Billed Duration: 1257 ms    Memory Size: 3072 MB    Max Memory Used: 161 MB Init Duration: 936.79 ms    
XRAY TraceId: 1-60ad0933-538a058068ffb9c91b0a0db9   SegmentId: 58c34b0d2f79867e Sampl
[2021-05-25T14:32:07.412Z ERROR cloudwatch_lambda_agent::logs::logs_server] Failed to deserialize log message.
    Err(Error("expected value", line: 1, column: 375))
    
    [
{
    "time": "2021-05-25T14:27:01.598Z",
    "type": "platform.end",
    "record": {
        "requestId": "ae61585c-9bda-480f-94e6-5b72f4ed7b17"
    }
}
,{"time":"2021-05-25T14:27:01.598Z","type":"platform.report","record":{"requestId":"ae61585c-9bda-480f-94e6-5b72f4ed7b17","metrics":{"durationMs":319.40,"billedDurationMs":1257,"memorySizeMB":3072,"maxMemoryUsedMB":161,"initDurationMs":936.79},"tracing":}}}]
```

it is started failing several weeks ago, apparently, there is a bug on the AWS side.
Has someone encountered the same error?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it seems that the problem is probably caused by the fact that **Active Tracing** is enabled on Lambda and the tracing information cannot be sent to the AWS Xray server (or the message cannot be interpreted). In my environment, changing the Active Tracing from **Active** to **Pass-Through** solved the problem. It seems that the problem is fundamentally with AWS itself, so I think you should contact AWS support.